# How to split text box value and check whether it is email ID or plain text in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays

I have a text box(txt_to) which has values seperated by ; How can I split the values, and even if there is only one value the code should not through error.

I tried to split it with the following code but got an error

```
string[] recipients = Request.Form["txt_to"].Split(';');
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

The values in the text box are either a email like (abc@aaa.com) or just a plain text like (Ios Group). the values in the text box are like abc@aaa.com; Ios Group. How to split the value and how to check whether it is email id or just a plain text

```
if(email id)
{
Do this
}
else if (Plain text)
{
Do this
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RFC 2822 states that you can validate an e-mail with the following regular expression:

```
[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?
```

So you can do:

```
if (Regex.IsMatch(input, **REGEX STRING HERE**))
{
    // E-mail
}
else
{
    // Not an e-mail
}
```

Answer (score 1):

string.Split doesn't throw an error when you split a string using a character that is not present in the string.

Example:

```
string test =  "jiberish";

string [] result = test.Split(';');
Console.WriteLine(result[0]);
```

Won't blow.  If you get a null reference exception is because `Request.Form["txt_to"]` is null

If you want to validate email addresses, use a Regular expression.

Something like:

```
if(Regex.IsMatch("\b[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b",yourstring))
{
   //valid email
}
else
{
   //not valid
}
```

Note: above regular expression may not be the most appropriate. I used it to give you an idea.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use a a `RegularExpressionValidator` for this:

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="regEmail" runat="server" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="*" ValidationExpression="^[\w\.\-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9\-]{1,})*(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}){1,2}$" ControlToValidate="txtEmail" />
```

Once implemented, you can verify that the field(s) are valid in code-behind like this:

```
bool isValid = Page.IsValid;
```

If you don't want to use validators, you can just use an expression in code-behind to validate the email address like this:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?");
bool isValid = regex.IsMatch(txtEmail.Text);
```

Here are a couple of expressions you can try out:

```
[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?

^[\w\.\-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9\-]{1,})*(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}){1,2}$
```

Answer (score -2):

You can simply do :

if the string contains an "@" than try to build a MailAdress object (in a try/catch) if it doesn't it's just plain text :)

```
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textToTest){
    try{
       mail = new MailAdress(textToTest);
    }catch(Exception e){
       plainText = textToTest
    }
}
```

EDIT : Update in order to take into account comments :)

Comment: This is literally the worst way to validate an e-mail. Do **not** simply check for an @ sign.

Comment: The MailAdress class will validate the adress.

Comment: Then why check for the @ sign anyway? Just use a try/catch.

Comment: @ykatchou yes, it will validate an email address but try/catch blocks are expensive. You should avoid them when you can simply use an if statement. This is a terrible way to validate an email address.

Comment: Id always prefer a solution like this without the use of complex regular expressions

Comment: Better to use a regular expression to validate the email address.

Comment: Regular expressions are not "complex", in fact, they are quickly becoming the standard for text validation. If you're still using .Contains() and .IndexOf(), you are living in the past.

Comment: Yes try catch is quite expensive, nonetheless it depends where you use it. If you only want to validate a value read from a file, it's quite enough.